# How to extract content in a cell using given criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm looking to extract some useful information from a large block of HTML looking codes via Excel.

When I copy the content onto Excel, all information is fitted onto 1 cell. I need to have them laid out in a readable format.

I'm hoping to extract the information between a given description, ending with `<`.

E.g. `<'abcde'>12345<'xx>`

If I give the criteria to be `<'abcde'>`, I'm hoping for the cell to return `12345`.

Is Excel capable of doing such things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel isn't equipped to parse HTML. You can play around with the `TEXT` functions and arrive at something which might work. It's usually more hassle than it's worth

As an example, this works if you give the tags either side as inputs

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"<'abcde'>",""),"<'xx>","")
```

---

This also works in a more generic sense, returning whatever is between two `<>` tags

```
=MID(A1,FIND(">",A1,2)+1,FIND("<",A1,2)-FIND(">",A1)-1)
```

Comment: Many thanks for your suggestions above. I've used assisting columns (Column B for the start, Column C for the end search), and placed the search content in Cell D2.

The formula I've used is `=MID($D$2,FIND(B4,$D$2,2)+LEN(B4),FIND(C4,$D$2,2)-FIND(B4,$D$2)-LEN(C4))`

For some reason most are still picking up an unwanted tail and some are giving me a `#VALUE!`

All data is copied and pasted so I can't figure out the reason - could you kindly enlighten me please. Thanks again!

Comment: @kitarika You probably want something like this: `LEN(C4) -1`  to remove the tail, and #VALUE are thrown when FIND doesn't find anything - you'll have to check that your search string can be found in D2

Comment: Thank you again. An example content would be `<pyde.02.00:PersonNameDetails.FamilyName.Text contextRef="MBRROLLVR01">Surname</pyde.02.00:PersonNameDetails.FamilyName.Text>` which I've placed in Cell D2, in Cell B18, I have `<pyde.02.00:PersonNameDetails.FamilyName.Text contextRef="MBRROLLVR01">`, and Cell C18 I have `</pyde.02.00:PersonNameDetails.FamilyName.Text>`. In D18, I've put the formula `=MID($D$2,FIND(B18,$D$2,2)+LEN(B18),FIND(C18,$D$2,2)-FIND(B18,$D$2)-LEN(C18))`, but it's still not giving me any values... everything else seems to work fine (except the name fields)...

Comment: Well, you should just use the solution I suggested in my answer above - it works!: `=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($D$2,$B$18,""),$C$18,"")`

Comment: It returned `Surname` for me. Try and make it work with a simple example: Maybe have the string `<a>TEST<b>` in `A1` and use `=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"<a>",""),"<b>","")`. Once you've got that working, adapt it to your other examples

Comment: Many thanks for all your help - I've figured out the issue. The ending criteria wasn't always unique, thus the formulas couldn't work properly if it located a match prior to the starting criteria. At the moment I've just shifted the search starting position for a temporary fix.

Answer (score 1):

In C2 (per supplied image) as,

```
=REPLACE(REPLACE(A2, FIND("<", A2, 2), LEN(A2), TEXT(,)), 1, FIND(">", A2), TEXT(,))
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. Unfortunately I do need the `<'abcde'>` and the `<'xx>` to be more agile - they need to become variables. I've started to use assisting columns being column B for the start variable and column C for the ending variable for the searches - would that be more helpful?